# Click Event inside of a jQuery Plugin on another element doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, event-handling, onclicklistener

I found many articles about this topic on stackoverflow but no one gave me a solution on my exact problem.

I have a jQuery Plugin which works fine so far. In that plugin I add some new `DIVs`. Also I want to add a click event listener on these new `DIVs`. Like this:

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.myFunc = function(options) {

    // Options + Defaults
    var settings = $.extend({
      // Some options in here
    }, options);

    var controls = "\
      <div class='controls'>\
        <button class='btn-add-text'>Add Text</button>\
      </div>\
    ";

    $('.btn-add-text').click(function() {
      alert("Test");
    });

    $(this).after(controls);

    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

My first thought was, that it is not possible because the event listener was called before the new div is actually inside of the DOM, so it can't work. So I moved the .click(func... Block outside of the plugin code and put it inside of a document.ready function like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-add-text').click(function() {
    alert("Test");
  });
});
```

This also won't work for me. Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use more variables to store html (jquery) elements.

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.myFunc = function(options) {

    // Options + Defaults
    var settings = $.extend({
      // Some options in here
    }, options);

    var button = $('<button class="btn-add-text">Add Text</button>');

    button.click(function() {
      alert("Test");
    });

    var controls = $('<div class="controls"></div>')
                   .append(button);

    $(this).after(controls);

    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

You use `$('.btn-add-text').click( ... )` and then you add this element to html with `$(this).after(controls)`. So jquery selector function can't find this element in html, becouse it is not here.

Also your concept isn't correct, becouse you add event listener on **all elements .btn-add-text** every time you call `myFunc` which can overload client javascript. Add event listeners only to elements that you are currently creating.

Comment: I did small edit. Your problem was in functions order. First insert element into html and then call selector which can add listener OR save dom/jquery element into variable, then add listener on it and then insert into html.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work on new DIVs you have to do something like -

```
$('.controls .btn-add-text').click(function() {
      alert("Test");
    });
```

If it doesn't work, then try disabling the cache and refresh.

**`Edit:`**

Overlooked something. Actually you are just registering the inner function(with 'options' parameter). You need to get it run to add the actual div element.

Your outer function is running because it is enclosed in () but the inner one is not.